# why isn't rstan working in this situation?

Tags: r, rstan

I was doing some exercises for Univeristy, when I came across this exercise, in which, its solution utilizes the rstan package. I installed it, along with StanHeaders, but I just can't get it work. I just get the following error:

```
Error in compileCode(f, code, language = language, verbose = verbose) : 
  /bin/sh: line 1: g++: command not foundmake: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-4.3.0/etc/x64/Makeconf:272: filea04b06519.o] Error 127
Error in sink(type = "output") : invalid connection
```

I've uninstalled R, installed the latest version, uninstalled rstan and StanHeaders and installed the preview of rstan 2.26 like I saw on some other websites, and it still doesn't work.
What do I dooooo?

Comment: Do you have Rtools43 installed?